# How can if (sscanf(buf, "%i", &mode) != 1 || TRUE) be rewritten to if (TRUE)?

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style

I got lost in the opening of [this post](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2e2ljn/nicks_fix_landed_in_linus_tree_bad_if_test/) on reddit.

How can `if (sscanf(buf, "%i", &mode) != 1 || TRUE)` be rewritten to `if (TRUE)`?  Does this assume that the `sscanf` never fails?

Comment: boolean logic: FALSE || TRUE always yields TRUE, from the very definition of "or".

Comment: If the processing inside the if statement uses the data located in buf, then yes we assume sscanf never fails.

Comment: It cannot be rewritten as just "if (TRUE)", because you DO need to do the scanf first as well (as the original post on reddit showed, but that detail was not included in the question here) for the code to be functionally identical. However, the test will always evaluate to true as mentioned by @BobDalgleish and others.

Comment: It's probably debug code to force the branch condition. It's after the sscanf because of short-circuiting semantics. Someone might write this code over other changes because it is presumably faster to test out a quick hack.

Comment: if (TRUE) isn't functionally equivalent, despite it having the same outcome to the "if" statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of the code calls sscanf and then ignores its return value assuming it is true. You can replace the code with 'if (TRUE)' provided that you call sscanf first.

Answer (score 3):

Using truth tables, you can show it will always return -EINVAL, thus,  don't even need the

```
if (TRUE)
   return -EINVAL;
```

it could be just

```
return -EINVAL
```

FWIW, since I don't have the context, this is almost certainly a bug. The

```
(mode != 2 || mode != 1)
```

probably should have been

```
(mode != 2 && mode != 1)
```

Comment: Correct. I guess this is code from a guy trolling and screwing up the kernel. Linux blacklisted him, but somehow this seeped in.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's assuming that even if sscanf *does* fail, it doesn't *care*.

Since the result is being ignored, I don't see the point of having this within the "if" at all.  I would *guess* that the sscanf call was originally on its own, then duff data started arriving (in **buf**) and messing up the sscanf call, so the "|| TRUE" was added to suppress the error.  Classic, Quick and Dirty fix.
Personally, I'd prefer to see this reworked:

```
sscanf( buf, "%i", &mode ); /* buf may or may not contain a valid mode */
```

Of course, the data item addressed by **&mode** might well be left in an inconsistent state - possibly a value parsed from **buf**, possibly not - but this code doesn't care either way.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is a smell? Using 'OR true' in a conditional statement is jarring to read and of no functional value.

if(statement OR true) { ... } would be better written as statement; { ... } ?

Comment: I would suggest looking up [Nick Krause linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=Nick+Krause+linux) on google.  The code is *intentionally* smelly and trying to be obscure.